# Google Play Developer policy violation что это?

Tags: android, google-play, permissions

Собственно получил от гугла письмо о том что мое приложение использует пермишены и просит дать ссылку на информацию о том что приложение(или) я не буду использовать данные в незаконных целях.

В следствии этого возникли вопросы:

1. Есть пример такого сообщения? Или это может быть в свободной форме?
2. Куда вставить ссылку? В сторе в описании приложения или в самом приложении?
3. У меня нет сайта. Где мне выложить данное сообщение, чтобы потом была ссылка? Посоветуйте сервис. Вообще гугловцы сами должны были бы предоставить что-то по проще.
4. Мне надо где-то отметится, что я предоставил ссылку или отработает робот?

Comment: Хочу сразу высказать возмущение что воспользоваться для данной цели сервисом `https://sites.google.com/` нельзя. Т.К. `Нельзя использовать Политику конфиденциальности из этого домена.`

Comment: Создал страницу на `facebook` надеюсь прокатит.

Comment: В консоле разработчика(В меню на одну позициию ниже "Загрузить apk") есть "Данные для google play" Это там где вы скриншоты загружаете. Есть сткрока "Политика конфиденциальности" вот туда и надо вставить ссылку на страницу любого сайта(я на Facebook создал) где написано что-то по типу "Это приложение не собирает, не обрабатывает и не высылает вашу конфиденциальную информацию куда либо или кому либо. Приложение делает то-то и то-то."

Comment: Спасибо, можете скинуть ссылку на ваше приложение?

Comment: Да собственно зачем? Это было тестовое приложение). https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bogdan.barscanner в самом низу есть пункт "Разработчик" => "Конфиденциальность" это ссылка на facebook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пишите privacy policy, выкладываете его куда-нибудь.
Не обязательно иметь свой адрес, можно даже открыть какой-нить бесплатный блог(коих великое множество) и там выложить. 
Линк вставляете в Google developer console, разделе "Данные для Google Play" в самом низу.
Все.
Либо удаляете чувствительные permission если она не нужны в аппликации.